# How to connect two logins in an android application?

Tags: android

I want to make an app kind of a parental control app.
I want two logins: parent and child. How do I connect parent and child through the same app? Like I want to send child's information on the parent login.
Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about this problem as how two pieces of data are related, each piece of data should have its own identification code, and there is a place to store data, such as a database, to store the relationship between them, such as A Contains the ID of the B, so that when your system obtains the A, it can know that it is related to the B.